# \unhbox of arabic text cause an uncorrect result

Tags: luatex, babel, arabic

Consider this example, why the result is uncorrect and how to fix it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\setbox0=\hbox{نص عربي}

\unhbox0

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably need to explicitly set the text direction in this case, since automatic bidi won’t work with output glyphs (the input charter information it needs is lost at this point).

Comment: @KhaledHosny I tried with `\textdir TRT \unhbox0` but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: No idea what is going on, but this works without babel `\setbox0=\hbox{\textdir TRT نص عربي}\unhbox0` (you need to set the direction inside the box, setting it outside is ignored by the box).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is Amiri uses the Private Use Area. Once the box is built, there is no information about the direction of the glyphs. If the direction is set explicitly with `\babelcharproperty` (I don't know the exact range), the text is rendered correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

% The following range is just a guess:
\babelcharproperty{980000}[990000]{direction}{al}

\begin{document}

\setbox0=\hbox{نص عربي}

\unhbox0

\end{document}
```

You may use this macro as a workaround, but I must investigate a better solution.

Comment: Yes the issue  appears only with `Amiri` font, thanks.