# Words apear incorrectly in tabular environment

Tags: tables, luatex, babel, arabic

[[image: enter image description here]]For the shown MWE, some words ( some of them are indicated in the code since most of the community is not familiar with Arabic) do not appear correctly, where some letters are reversed to be placed instead of others. The word still maintains all its letters but letter arrangement is changed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabu,multirow} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 

\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 


\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\begin{center}
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}?{1mm}c|} 

% the word (مَلاخيمْ) does not apear correctly
مُلُوكْ & مَلاخيمْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
نَفْسي & نَفْشِيْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should mention how you compile - that's important with bidi. And you should show the output so that everyone can check if they get the same.

Comment: I compile using LUALATEX

Comment: @Ulrike, I added an image for the compilation output

Comment: Sorry I don't have your font. Try to make an example with Amiri. And reduce the size of the tabular to one row if possible - that is easier for someone not familiar with the script,

Comment: A minimal example showing the bug with option `table` package xcolor 
`\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
اللغة\\  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I made an example with the amiri font, reduced the size of tabular to 2 rows. However, upon using the amiri font, things got much much worse, upon using the "simplified arabic" font, still there is a mess but things are better. YET upon using "TIMES NEW ROMAN" as the arabic font, things are clear and no issues are there. Any explanation, I am not quite sure if it is okay to use "Times new roman" as an Arabic font, since it is used for English language. So it seems to be a font issue, is there a way out of this?

Comment: @Salim, THe command "\newcolumntype{C}{>{\babelsublr\bgroup}c<{\egroup}}" is not working, upon running, the compilation runs normally but the output remains the same. Yet, the "m" solution works, replacing "c" with "m{width}" works. However, upon replacing the ARabic font "Amiri" with "Times new roman" it also works. SO: 1- Is there a way to get "\newcolumntype{C}{>{\babelsublr\bgroup}c<{\egroup}}" to work since it seems a better solution. Also, why does the "Times new roman" Font work without any of the porposed solutions?

Comment: @Salim, I am sorry, I did not notice that the defined column type is "C", not "c". So the command \newcolumntype{C}{>{\babelsublr\bgroup}c<{\egroup}} is working. What is the difference between the new defined column type "C" and the built in column type "c"??

Comment: Apparently the issue  appears only with Amiri font, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug with `xcolor` option `table` same issue with `colortbl`, the problem appear with `r` `c` `l` column type when using Amiri font

Apparently the issue is related to this [\unhbox of arabic text cause an uncorrect result](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505305/54817) and can be solved with Javier Bezos [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505424/54817)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% or \usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\babelcharproperty{980000}[990000]{direction}{al}    

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{tabular}{c} 
اللغة العربية  \\  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And your example become

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabu,multirow} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 


\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\babelcharproperty{980000}[990000]{direction}{al}  


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 


\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\begin{center}
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}?{1mm}} 
مُلُوكْ & مَلاخيمْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
نَفْسي & نَفْشِيْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]